# magento dropdown attribute is not saving in database

Tags: javascript, php, database, magento

we are using magento multi vendor site

we are using following code to update custom attribute "local" its working fine.

```
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner : Textfield
```

**phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('local');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "local[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="local_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldLocal(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valuelocal).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }




function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setLocal($upd_local);

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

In the same way, we are using following code to update custom attribute : "cod".
but its not saving in database.

```
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner : Dropdown
```

**phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "cod[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getCod(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedcod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="cod_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldCod('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="cod_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetCod('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function hideResetCod(product_id,codold) { 

var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuecod).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currcod).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldCod(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valuecod).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }




function updateFieldCod(product_id) 
{ 
var codId = '#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedcod_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldCod/')?>'; 
$cod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currcod).val($cod); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldCodAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_cod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setCod($upd_cod);

        $product->save();

        echo $cod = $product->getCod();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "cod[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
```

with

```
   <?php  $attribute_code = "cod"; $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code); $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); ?>
<select  id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "cod[]" ">
<?php foreach($options as $option){ 
       ?>
<option vaule="<?php echo echo $option["value"]; ?>"><?php echo $option["label"]; ?></option>


<?php } ?> </select>
```

Comment: i need this field as textfield also.

Comment: if you set to yes and not then you cannot change it

Comment: i want an option to edit "yes" or "no" as like other attributes.

Comment: but how you restrict user to choose only yes and no? dropdown is best option

Comment: okay please help me to make dropdown  : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Comment: any example dropdown?

Comment: this is the first one from dropdown

Comment: sorry don't understand what you want?

Comment: means, i did't created any attribute with drop down. this is the first attribute [dropdown] . i tried reindexing . but still not saving in database.

Comment: i am talking about cod attribute?

Comment: okay please help me to make dropdown? any example you have in mind?

Comment: the code you gave is already working s drop down : http://prntscr.com/9jt3w2 but its not saving in database

Comment: one more problem is there : by default all products are displaying "NO" as value. http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9jtwdy  i am using "notepad++" text editor, here color of "option value" is different from 2 lines. so its taking only line 1 code and displaying value as "NO".

did i missed code somewhere else ?

Comment: check there there is " option in that?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9jtwdy

when i removed the first line ,than its displaying "yes" for all.

when i keep the first line, by defult its dispalying "No" for all

Comment: `$attribute_value` copy this and check the value of database

Comment: before it was "cod_available" attribute code, now i changed to "cod"

Comment: if you change it then reindex  it

Comment: check the value are posting is 1 and 0?

Comment: install firbug in mozilla browser and inspect element

Comment: check here : http://prntscr.com/9ju7hv  XHR finished loading: POST "http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldCod/".

Comment: check the value in back end magento admin value is changing or not?

Comment: i checked it , its not reflecting in backend

Comment: this attribute is  gave by extension and there is no values in attribute section :

http://prntscr.com/9jubhb

Comment: did the attribute is product attribute and you can set value from admin panel?

Comment: i changed it. but its not reflecting in frontend.

Comment: admin side it reflecting?? can ou send me snapshot of product edit

Comment: no its not reflecting. and still it showing "NO" for all products in frontend. i tried with other custom attribute . in that if values is there than its displaying "YES", if values are not there, than its displaying "NO". i think problem with this attribute created by an extension.

Comment: admin end it is changing to yes to no?

Comment: code is working fine updated the answer of magento.stack check it

Comment: i tried it , but stil its displaying NO. here extension team did't gave any dropdown values when creating attribute

Comment: i know this yes not attribute.. it is reflecting in admin. print_r($product); and check the attribute is there?

Comment: which is displaying 1 and 1?

Comment: i just used this code : echo print_r($product); so 1111

Comment: use this print_r($products); and check the attribute is there? don't use echo

Comment: when i used this print_r($products);  , it did't displayed anything.

Comment: place where the loop starts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99281/discussion-between-profile-101-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: please check this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101629/skip-custom-shipping-method-step-in-checkout